# Disable RestAuthenticationFilter - Grails Spring Security Rest Plugin

Tags: rest, grails, spring-security-rest

I'm using Grails v2.4.2 with spring-security-rest, spring-security-core, and spring-security-ui plugins.

I'm trying to disable the RestAuthenticationFilter that comes with spring-security-rest so that I can write a custom Authentication Filter that is not case sensitive.

In my config.groovy, I'm using the following filter chain map:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
'/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,-restAuthenticationFilter'
```

]

I've added '-**restAuthenticationFilter**' to exclude RestAuthenticationFilter but it is still running.

How can I exclude RestAuthentication Filter or is there an easier way to add case insensitivity to the username when logging in through RestAuthenticationFilter?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like 2 different questions.

If you want exclude the REST auth filter, I think you need to remove restTokenValidationFilter and restExceptionTranslationFilter from the chain.

Try

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
'/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'
]
```

If you want to make your username case insensitive, just create a custom implementation of GrailsUserDetailsService. Implement loadUserByUsername to ignore case of the username.

See http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/userDetailsService.html

Comment: I know about the custom user details service, but can you implement that using the spring security rest plugin? I'm not seeing anywhere we use a UserDetailsService and all we are using Gorm for is token storage

Comment: Ah, so I see GormUserDetailsService is a class and part of grails-spring-security-core. I'll be writing a custom one of these instead.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin doesn't perform any authentication itself, but rather delegates it to the Spring's `AuthenticationManager`, which in turn uses any authentication provider configured. In your case, the provider used is [`DaoAuthenticationProvider`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#core-services-dao-provider), and it delegates user retrieval to the `userDetailsService` configured bean.

As @jstell pointed out, the core plugin provides a `GormUserDetailsService` that you will have to subclass, override the method `loadUserByUsername(String username, boolean loadRoles)`, and configure in `resources.groovy` as `userDetailsService` bean.